# GCP storage static site calling GCP function

Tags: java, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-403

I was given a "simple" assignment and can't seem to get it to work and the docs are not helpful at all.

Assignment:

1. create a POST function that receives a string and then returns the same string
2. create a static site (just an html form) that allows a user to submit a string which calls the above function.

I have a Java function deployed in GCP now that works via Postman, but I get a 403 anytime I try to call it from my local static site.

For postman to work, I used the cloud shell command: `gcloud auth print-identity-token`

I then took that token and put it in the Authorization Bearer Token header.

but, when I do that on the static site, I get the 403:

```
  fetch("https.myGoogleFunctionEndpoint.a.run.app", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain",
      "Authorization": "Bearer [myToken]
    },
    body: "Working!!!"
  })
    .then(response => response.body)
    .then(data => {
      console.log("Success:", data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
```

**I cannot use --allow-unauthenticated btw. It must stay private.**

How do show that I am an authenticated user?

I did create a user in the Identity platform, and can run [this command](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#section-sign-in-email-password) in order to get an ID token... But cant find anywhere that tells me what I am to do with that token... Or if I am even going in the right direction! And this is all just to test it locally, I haven't even uploaded my HTML and JS files to the bucket nor have I set up the api gateway...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the Java Fx btw:

```
package gcfv2;

import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class HttpMethod implements HttpFunction {
  @Override
  public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
      throws IOException {

    BufferedWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    switch (request.getMethod()) {
      case "GET":
        response.setStatusCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        writer.write("Hello world!");
        break;
      case "POST":
        response.setStatusCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        writer.write(request.getReader().readLine());
        break;
      default:
        response.setStatusCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_METHOD);
        writer.write("Something blew up!");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do all your users have a Google account (Gmail, workspace,...)?

Comment: No, they will be managed via SSO to an external account management system

Answer (score 0):

When creating the OIDC Identity Token, you must specify the `audience`, which is the Cloud Function URL.

[gcloud auth print-identity-token --audiences=URL_OF_CLOUD_FUNCTION](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-identity-token#--audiences)

Once you get past this part of development, you must implement OAuth in your application. Google has JavaScript [examples](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#creatingclient). Never hardcode tokens or credentials in your application, except those designed for that purpose.

[OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow)

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud functions accepts only Google Account (Gmail, Workspace, Service account,...) with IAM services.

Therefore, if your users are authenticated with a third party system (with SSO), you can't grant them directly to Cloud Functions

A solution is to deploy a proxy in front of your Cloud Functions, [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway), that checks [the authentication from your 3rd party](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-jwt) and then perform a [secure call to Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticate-service-account)

I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) with unmanaged equivalent, ESPv2. You can leverage it to set up your API gateway